# Why in interpreted languages the # usually introduces a comment?

Tags: comments, history, interpreted-language

Why in interpreted languages the # normally introduces a comment? This question was asked in an exam on Shell Programming but I don't find any hint on why it's the #.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because `--` and `//` and `/* ... */` require more characters to type and `#` isn't ususually used for anything else (such as pointer or mathematical notation)....I'm guessing?

Comment: @Frustrated - why did you post that as a comment, and not an answer?

Comment: That's a either stupid (we can't read the language designers' minds and it propably doesn't matter anyway) or obscure (if there's some hidden meaning, which would be *very* hidden). Halve the intensity of this rant if the teacher mentioned this (and not just in a small remark).

Comment: praise the gods it's `#` and not just any character in the first column

Comment: The /* ... */ style comments are more difficult for parsers than a comment introduced by a single character and running to the end of line. But why # rather than other character is not really clear or particularly useful.

Comment: @Andy White: Beacuse I have no idea if that is the REAL reason behind what the language designers were thinking. It was a best-guess, based on what *I* would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make uses the #-comment construct; and sh, one the first shells, uses the same #-comment. The writers of later shells -- csh, ksh, bash, jsh, and more -- understood that it would be a burden on users if each were to have its own comment convention, particularly since all of these shell scripts can sort-of run under any shell.

To invent yet another comment convention would be to ensure that no one would use any newly-introduced shell.

The #-comment became a de facto standard very early in Unix history.

That's my take, anyway.

-- pete