# Reasons and history for choice of common comment signs

Tags: language-agnostic, comments, interpreted-language, compiled-language

Most of the programming languages use `//` or `#` for a single line comment (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Comments)). It seems to be that `#` is especially used for interpreted languages. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995805/why-in-interpreted-languages-the-usually-introduces-a-comment) the reason for that seems to be that one of the early shells (bourne shell) used '#' as a comment and made use of it ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))).

Is there a logical reason why to choose `#` as a comment sign (e.g. symobolize crossing out by `#`)? And why do we use `//` as a comment sign in many compiled languages (especially in C as it seems to be one of the earliest compiled languages with that symbol)? Are there logical reasons for that? Why not use `#` instead of `//`, or `//` instead of `#`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/history/info

Comment: Are there any logical reasons for favoring green over blue?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, e.g. if i want to place important warning signs for people in a forest and i only have the choice between blue and green i would choose blue for them.

Comment: @SearchSpace - You'd favor red or yellow in that case, since you want them to stand out (and you aren't limited in either case). But that's beside the point. Your question asks for an explanation of something that is done by the fancy of language designers.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, i would choose the color appropriately for the application case (in this case i want the warning symbols to stand out and i would choose a color with high contrast). 
The question is why did the language designers favoured the choosen symbols (what was in mind for their application case -  as we had "standing out" in our mind). I don't think they took a dice/cube (you simply assume that their was no reason because you yet don't see it, but that doesn't guarentee that there exists no reason [it's just probably not as obvious as in the warning sign example]).

Comment: Overall, the choice of symbols and operators in C is wonderfully irrational. Symbols like `/`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `<`, `>` and `=` commonly appear in all kinds of completely non-related cases (for example consider `/* int* (*p)(int a[*]) = (type*)*x * *y; */`). There simply cannot be any rationale behind the symbol choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a logical reason why to choose `#` as a comment sign [in early shells]?

The Bourne shell tokenizer is quite simple. To add comment line support, a single character identifier was the simplest, and logical, choice.

The set of single characters you can choose from, if you wish to be compatible with both EBCDIC and ASCII (the two major character sets used at that time), is quite small:

      `!`   (logical not in `bc`)

      `#`

      `%`   (modulo in `bc`)

      `@`

      `^`   (power in `bc`)

      `~`   (used in paths)

Now, I've listed the ones used in `bc`, the calculator used in the same time period, not because they were a reason, but because you should understand the context of the Bourne shell developers and users. The `bc` notation did not arrive from out of thin air; the prevailing preferences influenced the choice, because the developers wanted the syntax to be intuitive, *at least for themselves*. The above `bc` notes are therefore useful in showing what kind of associations contemporary developers had with specific characters. I don't intend to imply that `bc` necessarily had an impact on Bourne shell -- but I do believe it did; that one of the reasons for developing the Bourne shell was to make using and automating tools like `bc` easier.

Effectively, only `#` and `@` were "unused" characters available in both ASCII and EBCDIC; and it appears *"hash"* won over *"at"*.

> And why do we use `//` as a comment sign in many compiled languages?

The `//` comment style is from [BCPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL). Many of the BCPL tokens and operators were already multiple characters long, and I suspect that at time the developers considered it better (for interoperability) to reuse an already used character for the comment line token, rather than introduce a completely new character.

I suspect that the `//` comment style has a historical background in margin notes; a double vertical line used to separate the actual content from notes or explanations being a clear visual separator to even those not familiar with the practice.

> Why not use `#` instead of `//`, or [vice versa]?

In both of the cases above, there is clear logic.  However, that does not mean that these were the only logical choices available.  These are just the ones that made the most sense to the developers at the time when the choice was made -- and I've tried to shed some light on the *possible* reasons, the context for the choices, above.

If these kinds of questions interest you, I recommend you find old math and science (physics in particular) books, and perhaps even reproductions of old notes. Best tools are *intuitive*, you see; and to find what was intuitive to someone, you need to find out the context they worked in. I am absolutely certain you can find interesting "reasons" -- things that made certain choices logical and intuitive to them, while to us they may seem odd -- by finding out the habits of the early developers and their colleagues and mentors.

Comment: Your argumentation about `//` has a flaw: C did not support it until C99. It was originally introduced with C++, but not C, thus there is a gap between BCPL and C++. Other languages used other formats, Pascal e.g. `(* ... *)`. I doubt one can really rationalise the choices made, most likely even the developers could not anymore. Just the "why not use `#` in C" is obvious: `#` is used for preprocessor directives.

Comment: @Olaf: No; `//` was originally introduced in BCPL, not C++. It was then inherited by B, but C prior to C99 went with block comment format. Soustrup's C-with-classes reintroduced the `//` comment format, but I don't know if it was because Soustrup liked B or BCPL or for some other reason. C99 reintroduced the `//` comment format, because most of the existing C/C++ compilers already supported it, and there was no downside to standardizing it. I do claim that the choices made were most affected by the dev's context; they were not as random as they might appear.

Comment: Where did I say it was introduced with C++? Nor did I say they were random. I wrote the devs themselves could not rationalise now why they picked them. That does not imply they were random. You seem to underestimate the influence of the subconscious.

Comment: @Olaf: Your second sentence is *"It was originally introduced with C++"*. The timeline was BCPL, B, K&R C, C with Classes, C++, ANSI C, C++ 2.0, ISO C (C89/C90), C++11, ISO C11, C++14. The gap was between BCPL and B; K&R dropped the `//` when they simplified the set of operators from BCPL to B.

Comment: @Olaf: If the devs cannot rationalize the original choices *now*, I'd chalk it up to forgetting. Yes, the subconscious has a huge influence on the choices -- and that's exactly what I mean by *context* --; I personally just don't see anyone that skilled making such choices without deliberation, based on ones vague intuition alone. At minimum, they have had personal preferences according to their experience with the earlier languages and environments -- perhaps even keyboard layouts. I claim that even the subconscious bias has a basis, and we could try to explore that via notes and biographies.

Comment: (Typo in a previous comment: It was Ken Thompson and later Dennis Ritchie who developed B; Dennis Ritchie started C, and Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie wrote the K&R book, "The C Language".)

Comment: The "original" refered to the two languages C and C++. Sorry for the missleading phrase. Not clear what you want to say with the timeline. I know quite well how the languages are related. Point is: the `//` comment was used before C and then in C++. C itself adopted it only with C99, i.e. neither K&R-C nor C89/90 (aka ANSI-C) allowed it (although many C90 compilers very soon supported it as an extension). Re the rest: I think you assume too much reason in this. It is surprising how many design-decissions are made purely by random.

Comment: @Olaf: Oh, now I understand. (Note: I assume others read these comments too, so I tend to list things even when I'm sure you already know them. Linear language hard, I must make extra effort.) True, I did not mention the history of `//` in C; I thought it would just confuse things as it was standardized in C99 mostly because the C compilers at that time already supported it -- i.e., as a practical measure, rather than seen as something the language lacked. Also true: I do probably overestimate the amount of logic applied. I'm a hopeless romantic, when it comes to logic and human behaviour.

Comment: It's a kind of chicken&egg type of question for C: Was it added to the standard because it was supported by the compilers or was it supported because it was in C++ and proved practical, expecially for in-code single documentation lines (which are by far the most common). With your information about the C predcessors (I didn't know about them), I suspect not supporting it was actually a flaw and oriented on Pascal that time which has only begin-end style comments.

Comment: Re rationalisation of human behaviour: I'm afraid the older I get, the more pessimistic I become about that.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm not young either. I tend to be optimistic about individuals, pessimistic about groups. I don't think the C standards committee cares about the language at all. It is an organization that protects the commercial interests of the member companies, and cares nothing about the language features, or developers' needs. Just look at C11: at a time when Microsoft didn't even fully implement C99, the committee included MS's *"safe"* I/O variants (`_s()`), but ignored tried and true features provided in POSIX (and just about every other C library implementation except MS's) like `getline()`.

Comment: Don't forget making VLAs optional in C11 which were mandatory in C99. That is completely against the policy of maintaining compatibility with previous versions, which they fight to the bone when it comes to eventually removing problematic legacies like old-style declarations, etc. And yes, they more preserve the status-quo than make C a modern language. That's actually what angers me most: there is just no other well defined, compact language without hidden run-time overhead, but clean type system. C could evolve to it, but I'm pessimistic, too.

Comment: (as a bare-metal embedded developer, I don't care much about the standard library, otoh)